# Is it possible to do this Android screen animation with a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-viewpager

I need to make 2 screens with custom animation like explained below :

```
          Screen 1                                    Screen 2
 -----------------------------              ------------------------------
|                   |         |            |        |                     |
|                   |         |            |        |                     |
|                   |         |            |        |                     |
|                   |         |            |        |                     |
|                   |         |            |        |                     |
|                   |         |            |        |                     |
|                   |         |            |        |                     |
|                   |         |            |        |                     |
|       List 1      |  List2  | ---------> | List 3 |      List 4         |
|                   |         |            |        |                     |
|                   |         |            |        |                     |
|                   |         |            |        |                     |
|                   |         |            |        |                     |
|                   |         |            |        |                     |
|                   |         |            |        |                     |
|                   |         |            |        |                     |
|                   |         |            |        |                     |
|                   |         |            |        |                     |
 -----------------------------              ------------------------------
```

- User makes a long touch on an item in List 1 and slides from left to right.
- The view containing List 1 moves from left to right (till the end of the screen) and fades. Screen 2 is shown.

Is it possible to do this animation using `ViewPager`? If yes, How?

I would like to do this via `ViewPager` because I'm using `Fragment`s pretty extensively and I have implemented many screens as fragments already.

If anyone needs clarification about the animation or the UI, please let me know.

**Update** : I was able to implement both of the screens in a single activity which I have partially explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022658/android-layout-animation-doesnt-stay-on-top/8141909#8141909). I can implement the same in a single fragment. But being able to implement as different `Fragment`s in a `ViewPager` would still help.

Comment: Can you give me the xml of the view so I can experiment? I have a simple and fast solution, but i prefer to try it. You have 4 listviews? i didnt get it well

Answer (score 3):

ViewPager, too me, seems like overkill. Unless you want to add more screens later, or some other requirement. For these simple screens you can do it with ActivityAnimations. If you put Screen1 and Screen2 in a seperate Activity, you can animate the Activities using simple styles. You don't need to code, simply define the Enter and Exit styles for your activities, and they will be executed.

So, unless you have another reason for using the ViewPager, you can accomplish the same effect by the following (not tested):

Android Manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".Screen1" android:theme="@style/Animated"></activity>
<activity android:name=".Screen2"></activity>
```

Your themes.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="Animated">
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/Animation.ScreenAnimation</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Finally, in your styles.xml

```
<style name="Animation"></style>
<style name="Animation.ScreenAnimation" parent="android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_right</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_left</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_out_left</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/slide_in_right</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I don't think this would solve the problem as only the view1 needs to be animated and not the entire screen.

Comment: Perhaps I don't fully understand the question, and you do need a ViewPager. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully used vertical ListViews inside of ViewPagers before. How about trying a horizontal scrolling list view inside of your ViewPager?