# Android - Layout Animation Doesn't stay on top

Tags: android, android-animation

I need to make 2 screens with custom animation like explained below :

```
          Screen 1                                    Screen 2
 -----------------------------              ------------------------------
|                   |         |            |        |                     |
|                   |         |            |        |                     |
|                   |         |            |        |                     |
|       List 1      |  List2  | ---------> | List 3 |      List 4         |
|   (75% width)     |(25% wid)|            |(25%wid)|   (75% width)       |
|                   |         |            |        |                     |
|                   |         |            |        |                     |
 -----------------------------              ------------------------------
```

- User makes a long touch on an item in List 1 and slides from left to right.
- The view containing List 1 moves from left to right (till the end of the screen) and fades. Screen 2 is shown.

I have put each of the lists in a `LinearLayout`and all the `LinearLayout`s is contained in a root `LinearLayout`. After detecting the left to right swipe on `List1`, I do this

```
                        AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

                        Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
                            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.75f,
                            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f
                        );
                        animation.setDuration(500);
                        animation.setZAdjustment(Animation.ZORDER_TOP); // Keep the viewgroup on which this animation applies at the top.
                        set.addAnimation(animation);

                        LayoutAnimationController controller =
                            new LayoutAnimationController(set, 0.0f);

                        screenOne_layoutOne.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
                        screenOne_layoutOne.startLayoutAnimation();
```

I was able to get the animation but the `screenOne_layoutOne`(layout containing the `List 1`) doesn't stay on top. The animation goes below `List2`.

Can anyone tell me where the problem is?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you who are interested, I was able to get this solved by putting the layouts of both the  screens in a single layout file and changing the `visibility` of the layouts/views. The layout file used is

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/featured_view_container"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <ListView android:id = "@+id/featured_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

    <ImageView android:layout_height = "match_parent" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/seperator"/>

    <LinearLayout android:id = "@+id/categories"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- Layout for the screen 2-->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/category_view_container"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <LinearLayout android:id = "@+id/subcategories"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView android:layout_height = "match_parent" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/seperator"/>

    <ListView android:id = "@+id/subcategory_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

when I applied the animation(`anim`) on list1(`featured_list`), it stays on top if I do

```
                    anim.setZAdjustment(Animation.ZORDER_TOP)
```